# How to increase a video frame rate using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation

I want to increase the video frame rate using AVFoundation.

My approach is simple: I plan to duplicate each frame and reduce its duration.

For example, If I want to double my frame rate, I will duplicate each frame and half each of its duration.

**What I have tried:**

I start with a simple code to read each frame of video.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
    do {
        let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)

        let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: nil)
        reader.add(readerOutput)
        reader.startReading()
        var nFrames = 0
        while true {
            let sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            
            if let sampleBuffer {
                let timingInfo = UnsafeMutablePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>.allocate(capacity: 1)
                let newSample = UnsafeMutablePointer<CMSampleBuffer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
                
                CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(sampleBuffer, at: 0, timingInfoOut: timingInfo)
                print("\(nFrames):")
                print(timingInfo.pointee.duration)
                print(timingInfo.pointee.presentationTimeStamp)
                
                nFrames = nFrames+1
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        print("Num frames: \(nFrames)")
        return nFrames
    }catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

But the timing info isn't what I expected. Most of them are zero.

```
0:
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
1:
CMTime(value: 413, timescale: 600, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 600, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)
2:
CMTime(value: 413, timescale: 600, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 413, timescale: 600, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)
3:
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
4:
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
5:
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 0, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 0), epoch: 0)
```

**Question:**
Is this a doable and right approach? Why does the timing of each frame are zero?

Can anyone direct me to the right resources or solutions for this?

Here is the file I want to increase fps https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/nl6yabgl9yzikx12mkvnu/sample2.mp4?rlkey=wk4fsu2vvkcui31cneq8vruik&e=1&dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
do {
    let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)

    let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
    let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: nil)
    reader.add(readerOutput)
    reader.startReading()
    var nFrames = 0
    while let sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
        if let timingInfo = CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(sampleBuffer, at: 0) {
            print("\(nFrames):")
            print(timingInfo.duration)
            print(timingInfo.presentationTimeStamp)
        }
        nFrames += 1
    }
    print("Num frames: \(nFrames)")
    return nFrames
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).